# Symbol for "take the positive solution of this formula"

Tags: education

I got a formula:

x=√(((−2*a*k*s)/(r*(s-k)*v)))

Notice it is all wrapped inside a square root.

---

**When taking the square root, there are to possible outcomes as we all know. How do I denote that one should use the positive number?**

Comment: What are the Solutions of this Problem?

Comment: Depends on what you set the variables to be. Eg. "x_1=2, x_2=-4".

Comment: $\sqrt{a}$ means the positive square root of $a$.  It's a common error to somehow push the $\pm$ in  $\pm \sqrt{a}$ into the $\sqrt{a}$.  Your "two possible outcomes" requires you to write $\pm\sqrt{a}.$

Answer (score 1):

That one. $\sqrt{a}$ denotes the positive solution of the equation $x^2 = a$.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula does not require any change. By definition, $x = \sqrt{a}$ will return only the non-negative square root, or the principal square root. You’re confusing this with $x^2 = a \iff \vert x\vert = \sqrt{a}$, which has two solutions: $x = \pm \sqrt{a}$.

Therefore, $x = \sqrt{a}$ already implies that the returned value isn’t negative. (Note that there is no $\pm$ sign in front of the square root.)